# asp.net mvc 3 identify version

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

how can i determine that i am using the final version of mvc 3?

Answer (score 1):

The RTM version of the MVC 3 System.Web.Mvc.dll file should have a product/file version of 3.0.20105.0.